# C - Weird symbols

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, symbols, logical-operators

i'm new to c and i've mostly dealt with writing code using loops so far but i've come across this problem which contains some symbols i've never seen before. Could you explain why these numbers are showing when I compile and run?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {

int i = 23, j = 13, k = 11, m;
printf("%d\n", i || j && k);
printf("%d\n", i | j & k);
m = i == j && k;
printf("%d %d\n", m, -!m < 0);
m = i ^ (j=13);
printf("%d %d\n", m, j);
j = 7;
m = 7;
m = i & ~(j==7);
printf("%d\n", m);
m = ~(~k | k);
printf("%d\n", m);

}
```

I get:

1 - 
31 -
0 1 -
26 13 -
22 -
0

Comment: This question isn't constructive as it is. There's no way to tell which symbols you are unfamiliar with. Can you narrow it down and make it more specific ?

Comment: First printf, why does 1 come out? Second why does 31 come out, never seen only one | and &, usually they're in groups of two. Third, "m = i == j && k;" how does this work, and what is '-!m < 0'? 4th 'm = i ^ (j=13);' 5th m = i & ~(j==7); 6th m = ~(~k | k);

Answer (score 2):

Since you did not specify which operators you are unfamiliar with I will go through a general run down of a few of them and link you to a few resources you can read on your own time. There are a combination of [logical operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++) and [bitwise operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C). Such as:

1. `&&` implies logical operator, AND.
2. `||` implies logical operator, OR.
3. `~` implies bitwise operator, NOT.
4. `!` implies logical operator, NOT.
5. `&` implies bitwise operator, AND.
6. `|` implies bitwise operator, OR.
7. `^` implies bitwise operator, XOR.
8. `==` implies logical operator, equality.
9. `=` implies assignment operator.
10. ... etc.

... the rest you can find on the two pages I linked and logically deduce their results from there.

Comment: You forgot `^`, the bitwise XOR

Comment: @typ1232, for completeness I'll add it. I did say *some* of the operators are listed here though.

Answer (score 1):

If by weird symbols you mean ||, &&, | and & symbols then these are the logical and bitwise operators.

```
printf("%d\n", i || j && k);
```

will evaluate like this:

First j && k is evaluated: It is the logical AND operator. If both of these values are non-zero then the result is 1. (If any of these were zero then the result would have been zero.)

Then this result is "ORed" with i by logical OR operator ||. This means if any of the left and right hand operator is non zero then the result is 1. Which is the result here.

Code:
    printf("%d\n", i | j & k);

This code is used for bitwise operations.

The binary representation of i, j and k can be written as:

```
i = 23 = 00010111
j = 13 = 00001101
k = 11 = 00001011
```

Now first j & k is evaluated: you can apply the bitwise AND operation on all the bits. 
The result will be: 00001001

Then this is ORed with value of `i` this time also bitwise. So the result will be:

```
  00001001
  00010111
= 00011111 = 31
```

You can apply similar logic for other operators. You can find more about these operators in all basic text books for the language.